# Let $S$ be a countable set in $\mathbb R^2$. Prove that there exists a line that does not contain, any point from $S$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, analytic-geometry

The answer is given and up until a certain point it is clear. I would very much appreciate if anyone could help out understanding the solution after that point.

$$S \subset \mathbb R^2 \ \ \ \ |S|=\lambda_0 \ \ \ \ |\mathbb R^2|=c \ \ \ \ S \subset \mathbb R^2 \implies \exists x_0\in \mathbb R^2 \setminus S$$

Let $p$ be a line that contains point $x_0$. Let $H_1,H_2$ be a half-planes that define $p$.From this point is where I have troubles, all the way to the end:

$$p(x_0,\overline{x}), \overline{x}\in S, \theta \in [0,2\pi] \ \ \overline{x}\leftrightarrow\theta \\ |[0,2\pi]|=c \\ \ \overline{x}=\theta\overline{x} \ \ \ \ \  \{\theta\overline{x}|\overline{x}\in S\}= \lambda_0 \\ \{\theta\overline{x}|x\in S\}\subset[0,2\pi] \implies \exists \overline{\theta}\in [0,2\pi]\setminus \{\theta \overline{x}| \overline{x} \in S\}$$

Comment: In english this is easy: Just rotate your $p$ around $x_0$, this gives you uncountably many lines, so one of them will contain no $S$.

Comment: Where does this proof come from? Horribly written.No quantifiers, no mention of where the fixed entities lie and hardly no words to accompany badly used symbols.

Comment: I would project $S$ on a coordinate axis and then take a line orthogonal to it and not passing an image of the projection as example. seems like in your (horribly sketchy) proof someone does that for the projection on the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I'll take a look at them in more detail tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative proof. Denote by $\mathcal{L}$ the set of horizontal lines in the plane. Define the function $f: S \to \mathcal{L}$ by associating to each point $x \in S$ the horizontal line $\ell \in \mathcal{L}$ passing through that point. You know that $S$ is countable and $\mathcal{L}$ uncountable.

Thus $f$ is not surjective (or else $card(S) \geq card(\mathcal{L})$). This means that there exists a horizontal line which does not contain any point in $S$.

Comment: @  Beni  Bogosel    by your method one can choice a line of an arbitrary direction.

Comment: Yes, of course.